# scala.collection.immutable.List[Int] vs custom List constructor List[Int]

Tags: scala, list, constructor

I am new to scala. be gentle.
I think the problem is that I created a Trait List which conflicts with scala.collection.immutable.List

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head[T]
  def tail[T]
}

class Cons[T](val head:T, val tail: Option[List[T]]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  def head[T] = head
  def tail[T] = tail
}

class Nil[T] extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  def head[T] = throw new IllegalStateException("head")
  def tail[T] = throw new IllegalStateException("tail")
}

// ERROR HERE
// obj with one elem
val one: Cons[Int] = new Cons[Int](1,Option(scala.List[Int]()))
```

> the error is:  expected scala.Option[List[Int]],  actual
>   scala.Option[scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]]

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you are passing a `scala.List[Int]` instead of your `List[Int]`. That's exactly what the error message says. You probably intended to pass `None`.

Comment: Note: this is only one of 12 errors I counted during a quick glance on your code.

Comment: Ok, actually, @JörgWMittag is right - there seem to be a few other errors. Bunch of random hints: 1) `head` and `tail` don't need their own type parameter. 2) `Option` does not belong there, you already have `Nil` for that. 3) `head` and `tail` need proper result types. 4) You probably want to make both classes `case` classes, and remove `val`s. 5) You don't need `[Int]` in `Cons[Int]`, it should be inferred. 6) You probably want a `sealed trait`.

Comment: Sorry, about 1) head and tail don't need their own type parameter. i get errors if i remove that. i do not understand. Also for 5) You don't need [Int] in Cons[Int]. i get errors when i remove it from cons.

Comment: I added a bit of explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `tail` to be of type `Option[List[T]]`, but you are passing it the result of calling `Option(scala.List[Int]())`, which is syntactic sugar for `Option.apply(scala.List[Int].apply())`.

`scala.List[Int].apply` returns a `scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]`, not a `List[Int]`. I am not sure why you would expect a built-in Scala method to return an object that it doesn't know anything about. Anyway, the correct solution for this particular error would be to pass an instance of *your* `Nil` class instead of trying to pass *Scala's* `Nil`.

This has nothing to do with you choosing the name `List` for your trait. You would have gotten the same error with any other name.

---

Let's take a closer look at your code:

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head[T]
  def tail[T]
}
```

You didn't declare a type for `head` and for `tail`. This means that the default type that is going to be used is `Unit`, which means that those methods don't return anything, they only have side-effects. As a result, the following is perfectly legal:

```
class Cons extends List[Int] {
  override def isEmpty = false
  override def head[Int] = Unit
  override def tail[Int] = Unit
}
```

In fact, since a return type of `Unit` means that the return value is just thrown away, even this is legal:

```
class Cons extends List[Int] {
  override def isEmpty = false
  override def head[Int] = "Hello"
  override def tail[Int] = true
}
```

So, what you probably want is to declare the return types:

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head[T]: T
  def tail[T]: T
}
```

Another problem is that you are declaring a trait with a type parameter `T`, then declaring a method `head` with a *different* type parameter which just happens to have the same name and thus shadows the outer `T` and declare a method `tail` with yet another different type parameter.

This is exactly equivalent to

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head[U]
  def tail[V]
}
```

There is exactly zero relationship between the three type parameters.

What this means is that for example the following class is perfectly legal:

```
class Cons extends List[Int] {
  override def isEmpty = false
  override def head[String] = "Hello"
  override def tail[Float] = 1.23
}
```

And in fact, since you never use `T` anywhere, you can just leave it out:

```
trait List {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head[U]
  def tail[V]
}
```

And likewise for `U` and `V`, so what you have *actually* written is more or less this:

```
trait List {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head
  def tail
}
```

But that is not what you intended at all, I would guess!

It *seems* that you actually expect all the three `T`s to be the same. But! That cannot possibly work, since the `head` is a single element and the `tail` is a list (or in your case an optional list) … how can a single element and an option of a list possibly have the exact same type? That's impossible!

What you (probably) want instead is something like this:

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: Option[List[T]]
}
```

Note, however, that the `Option` doesn't make sense either, since you later actually create a special class to represent an empty list (`Nil`), you don't need to have an `Option` here. That is going to be massively confusing because you can have either an existing empty list or a non-existing list but they both mean the same thing. Let's just get rid of the `Option`:

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
```

Lastly, you will notice that we can only ever take elements *out* of our list, but never put something *in*. (We can only construct *new* lists that have additional elements.) This means that our list is actually *covariant* in its element type, so let's make sure Scala knows this:

```
trait List[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
```

Also, note that you want to make sure that there can only be two subclasses of this: an empty list and a non-empty list. You don't want to have a third kind of list. Therefore, you should make it a `sealed trait` so that it can only be subclassed within the same compilation unit:

```
sealed trait List[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
```

Now, let's look at the `Cons` class.

```
class Cons[T](val head:T, val tail: Option[List[T]]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  def head[T] = head
  def tail[T] = tail
}
```

Again, you have the same shadowing going on here. You don't want three different type parameters, you only want one:

```
class Cons[+T](val head: T, val tail: Option[List[T]]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def head = head
  def tail = tail
}
```

Note also that in your original version, the return types of both `head` and `tail` were `Unit`, so the return values would have just been thrown away.

Again, let's get rid of the `Option`, since we *know* that there will always a be a `tail`, that's what we have `Nil` for, to represent an empty `tail`:

```
class Cons[+T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def head = head
  def tail = tail
}
```

Also, the `val` declaration in the constructor already creates a getter method, so we can get rid of those:

```
class Cons[+T](override val head: T, override val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  override def isEmpty = false
}
```

Also note that we are not computing anything in `isEmpty`, so there is no need for it to be a method and re-evaluate `false` every time; we can simply make it a field:

```
class Cons[T](override val head: T, override val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  override val isEmpty = false
}
```

And again, we don't want someone to create another subclass of `Cons`, because we want to make sure that there are only two. Therefore, we make `Cons` a `final` class:

```
final class Cons[+T](override val head: T, override val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  override val isEmpty = false
}
```

And, for convenience, let's also make it a `case class`, so we can use pattern matching on constructor arguments, get a nice automatically defined implementation of `toString()` and `##`, and a companion object with an `apply` factory method:

```
final case class Cons[+T](override val head: T, override val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  override val isEmpty = false
}
```

And lastly, all of that applies for `Nil`, too, I am not going to go through the same detailed steps again:

```
final case class Nil[+T]() extends List[T] {
  override val isEmpty = true
  override def head: Nothing = throw new IllegalStateException("head")
  override def tail: Nothing = throw new IllegalStateException("tail")
}
```

However, note that it does not make sense to have an "empty list of integers", an "empty list of strings" and so on. An empty list is an empty list. Period. There is only one empty list.

So, let's make it an object instead:

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override val isEmpty = true
  override def head = throw new IllegalStateException("head")
  override def tail = throw new IllegalStateException("tail")
}
```

This works, because our list is covariant (meaning that a `List[X]` is a subtype of `List[Y]` if `X` is a subtype of `Y`) and `Nothing` is a subtype of every type; therefore `List[Nothing]` is a subtype of every `List[T]` and thus we can substitute `Nil` everywhere a `List[T]` is expected, regardless of what `T` is.

Finally, we may want to supply a `List` companion object with an `apply` factory method for conveniently constructing a `List`:

```
object List {
  def apply[T](elements: T*) = elements.foldRight(Nil: List[T])(Cons.apply)
}
```

In total, our code now looks like this:

```
sealed trait List[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}

final case class Cons[+T](override val head: T, override val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  override val isEmpty = false
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override val isEmpty = true
  override def head = throw new IllegalStateException("head")
  override def tail = throw new IllegalStateException("tail")
}

object List {
  def apply[T](elements: T*) = elements.foldRight(Nil: List[T])(Cons.apply)
}

val one = Cons(1, Nil)
//=> one: Cons[Int] = Cons(1, Nil)

val three = List(1, 2, 3)
//=> three: List[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))

val zero = List(1, 2, 3)
//=> zero: List[Nothing] = Nil

// Even pattern matching works:
val (hd Cons tl) = List("a", "b")
//=> hd: String       = "a"
//=> tl: List[String] = Cons("b", Nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
 val one: Cons[Int] = new Cons[Int](1, None)
```

Or if you want a list of more than one element:

```
val two: Cons[Int] = new Cons[Int](1, Some(new Cons[Int](2, None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I belive (since I overwrite the class List in some way) that I should use my custom "constructors" all the way. So this is the correct line of code:

```
val one: Cons[Int] = new Cons[Int](1,Option(new Nil[Int]()))
```